# p-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, storage, aws

I am facing that

```
ap-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

warning when trying to run basic commands like `cd <directory_name>` in one of my instances.

The weird thing is that I am not facing that issue when running the commands as the root user. Also, I am not understanding why the warning has mentioned no space left on the device although there is enough space in the instance I think. Because the root volume of the instance was 100GB. I will share a screenshot below from the instance I hope it can helpful for explaining better.

Because I am also a little new for server stuff so might I am missing something :) May I know how can I fix that issue?

[image: screenShot]

Comment: sure, xvda is 100GB, but the partition xvda1 is 8GB and is 100% used

Comment: `sudo mount -t tmpfs nul /tmp` will fix this temporarily but you gotta do something about your root fs which is 100% full.

Comment: May I know what does it do that `sudo mount -t tmpfs nul /tmp` command? Also, how can I increase my root size? thanks

Comment: 1. [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.  2. If there are no other partitions in use on your xvda disk, you can expand the xvda1 partition (and then the filesystem on it) up to the full size of the disk.  Exactly how to do that depends on what fs the partition is formatted with.  Easiest method is to reboot with a rescue CD with `gparted`

Comment: BTW, some filesystems, like ext4 on linux, reserve some space for root's use only (e.g. so that root can fix out of space errors).  That's why you're not (yet) getting disk full errors as root.  The default for ext4 is to reserve 5% for root. This can be changed when formatting the partition with `mke2fs` or later with `tune2fs` (you can also set which uid & gid are allowed to use this reserved space - there's usually no good reason to change these).   5% is a lot on modern multi-terabyte drives, so it's not uncommon to reduce that to 1 or 2%.  On an 8GB partition, 5% is 400MB.

Comment: `sudo mount -t tmpfs nul /tmp` will (surprise!) mount [`tmpfs`][https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html], which, as quick googling can discover, "allows the creation of filesystems whose contents reside in virtual memory." Since your /tmp is not on a separate partition, and is affected by the fact that your entire root fs is full, this command will temporary mount part of the RAM on your /tmp so it would have free space available for commands that need temporary files. But again, please check what fills up your root fs and clean it.

Comment: If disk space is sufficient, as you say, check inodes available on your disk. this can be checked with `df -i` There may be chance you depleted inodes, especially if you created a lot of files, small in size, but big in amount.

Comment: What's in the screenshot? Please don't post pictures of text